# PHP - ob_start - replace text to call a function

Tags: php, html

I have:

**PHP**

```
<?php

function first_function() {
  return "A";
}

function second_function($first, $second) {
  return $first . $second;
}

ob_start(function ($buffer) {
  return $buffer;
});

?>
```

**HTML** for example

```
<h1>@first_function</h1>

<h2>@second_function(A, B)</h2>
```

My question: How can I do this in HTML to call entered functions with ob_start();?

**UPDATE**

I need to replace text @first_function with `<?php echo first_function(); ?>` && @second_function(A, B) with `<?php echo second_function("A", "B"); ?>`

Comment: I'd look into existing tempting projects if possible, otherwise you could build a pattern matching mechanism for your token `@second_function(A, B)` and then apply a find and replace whilst making use of `call_user_func*` functions, trying to parse your function parameters will be the most difficult part,.

Comment: Well, if I understand it right, your code should looks like: `<h1><?php echo @first_function() ?></h1>`

Comment: @felipsmartins - <h1><?php echo first_function(); ?></h1>